# IEnumerable, lambda covariance and extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable, covariance

I have an extension method to filter types implementing an interface, using a predicate taking a parameter typed to that interface:

```
public interface ILifeTrack
{
    DateTimeOffset? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}

public class LifeTrack : ILifeTrack
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> GetIsActiveExpression<T>()
    where T : ILifeTrack
    {
        return e => e.CreatedOn != null && e.DeletedOn == null;
    }

    public static readonly Expression<Func<ILifeTrack, Boolean>> isActiveExpression;
    public static readonly Func<ILifeTrack, Boolean> isActiveFunc;

    static LifeTrack()
    {
        isActiveExpression = GetIsActiveExpression<ILifeTrack>();
        isActiveFunc = isActiveExpression.Compile();
    }

    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}


public static class IEnumerableOfILifeTrackExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MetadataActive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> instance)
        where T : class, ILifeTrack
    {
        return instance.Where(LifeTrack.isActiveFunc);
    }
}
```

but when using the extension method, an exception is raised to indicate that the source IEnumerable<> is null:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
...
```

I know for sure that the instance passed to the extension method is not null, as these alternative forms work as expected:

```
instance.Where<T, T>(LifeTrack.isActiveFunc);
instance.Where(e => LifeTrack.isActiveFunc.Invoke(e));
Enumerable.Where<T>(instance, LifeTrack.isActiveFunc);
```

VS shows that

```
instance.Where(LifeTrack.isActiveFunc)
```

is deduced to

```
instance.Where<T, ILifeTrack>(LifeTrack.isActiveFunc)
```

Now I think that internally some casting is involved and at a point a downcasting fails resulting in a null reference, but what really happens behind the scenes?

---

madreflection is right, I had the following extension method in place, to try to overcome the same problem:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T, TI>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, Func<TI, bool> predicate)
    where T : class, TI
    {
        return Enumerable.Where(instance, predicate) as IEnumerable<T>;
    }
```

Terrible oversight from myself, but what's the proper way to handle the problem of using a covariant Func in .Where?

I think it should be

```
instance.Where<T>(LifeTrack.isActiveFunc)
```

but I still don't get why it needs  explicit typing.

Comment: It says the exception is being thrown by `ToList`, not your extension method. Where are you calling `ToList`?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile for me, let alone throwing an exception.

Comment: Since when did `Where` start accepting 2 generic type arguments?

Comment: It is called like this: var activeRecords = records.MetadataActive().ToList(), and I can confirm the reference returned in MetadataActive() is null before it is passed to ToList();

Comment: Break it into two statements so you can test the return of `MetadataActive` before calling `ToList`. Sweeper is right, `Where` (as provided by the framework) only has one type parameter. Check your code to see if you have a custom implementation that could return `null`.

Comment: My assumption would be that your `instance` list contains `null` references. Since your `isActiveFunc` will throw an exception on those the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` will be null and then the `ToList()` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. So either fix the filter function to handle `null` references or make sure they don't exist in your `instance` list.

Comment: The exception is `ArgumentNullException` and the parameter name is `source`. The name of of `Func<T, TResult>`'s parameter is `arg`. It's not the delegate that's throwing. It's hitting `ToList`'s initial null parameter check and throwing there.

Comment: @madreflection Seems I missed the difference in exceptions. Though for the record the example I gave will hit the `ToList()` (deferred excecution) so the stack trace will actually contain that exact line as quoted in the question (but with other stuff as wwll)

Comment: Regardless, `ToList` will not receive `null` because `Where` (the framework's version) won't ever return `null`. The difference in exception makes all the difference in tracking down the root cause. There must be a custom `Where` method here that's returning `null`, as having *two* type parameters suggests.